# Problems with Spyder 3 in macOS Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, macos-sierra

I have recently installed the latest conda distribution on macSierra. I have encountered many problems:

1) My main concern is that Spyder crashes eventually, especially when switching between applications and coming back to Spyder the rotating wheels keeps eternally spinning and unresponsive. This happens after ~10 minutes of use. I have tried spyder with different graphic backend for ipython and the problem still happens. When launching spyder the following message appears:

```
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
```

repeated 9 times.

3) When plotting figures, figures I create **after** calling

```
close('all')
```

open and close immediately. I never encountered this behaviour previously.

My conda distribution is the following:

```
           platform : osx-64
      conda version : 4.2.9
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.9
conda-build version : 2.0.2
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.11.1
   root environment : //anaconda  (writable)
default environment : //anaconda
   envs directories : //anaconda/envs
      package cache : //anaconda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with Spyder itself but with Qt, the graphical library on top of which Spyder is built on.

The current Qt version in Anaconda (**5.6.0**) does not support macOS Sierra. According to this [Github comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5163#issuecomment-249350576), the first versions that do it are **5.6.2** and **5.7.1**.

As soon as Continuum (the company behind Anaconda) updates Qt to one of these versions, I'm pretty sure those strange problems you're seeing will be solved.