# Why does Spyder not display my graphics output anywhere when I am using Pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, anaconda, spyder

I managed to install Pygame into my MacOS anaconda python 3.6 instance -- I simply put it into the "root" environment. The way I installed -- when I knew that the anaconda python was activated, I simply went to the command line and did pip install pygame.

But now, when I am in Spyder, and I load up a smallish python app that I wrote that uses Pygame, the app seems to run OK with no errors BUT it does not show the graphics output in any window or tab anywhere! I've tried alt-tabbing around...   [For comparison... when I tried to run another small app I made that uses tkinter, then it presents the graphics by creating a separate app/window I can alt-tab to... shows a feather as the icon for that window when I alt tab to it.]

I played a little with the Spyder preferences>Ipython preferences>graphics... tried "Automatic," "inline," and Tkinter... none had any effect.

Two supporting things:

1-- note that, when I run anaconda's Spyder from the command line, for some reason it shows this string of warning errors... any tips on this for me? It is:

```
Erics-MacBook-Pro:~ ericstephan$ spyder
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[[and six more lines of the same]]
```

2-- If it helps troubleshoot, below I will paste my pygame-using app whose graphics appears nowhere in Spyder. Makes many many little confetti sprites that flutter and bounce. Hey, it's a fun little app, if you replace numdots with something big like 500, it's pretty cool... when it's visible!
Here is the problem pygame app: Stackexchange editor wouldn't allow it so you can see it at https://pastebin.com/1Aa8pVDq

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Point **1.** is not related to this, you can ignore it. This seems like a bug, so please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we don't forget to take a look at it.

Comment: Hey Carlos -- Thank you!  I have created a new item about this pygame thing in the issue tracker you linked. My issue item is:  https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4471  ... thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing it!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with spyder but with Qt (graphics library for spyder).
Current Qt version in Anaconda does not support macOS sierra. For more details: [stackoverflow.com - Problems with Spyder 3 in macOS 10.12 (Sierra) or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40424301/8782672)